# Установка удаление Apache 2.4

Tags: apache2.4

При выполнении команды

```
Apache24\bin\httpd.exe -k install
```

написал `instal` с одной `l`. Команда выполнилась с ошибкам. После этого Apache перестал запускаться и выдает ошибку :

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>c:\Server\bin\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe -k restart
>       [Sun Aug 27 22:44:36.780315 2017] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 884:tid 144] (OS 2)═х єфрхЄё  эрщЄш єърчрээ√щ Їрщы.  : AH00436: No installed service named "Apache2.4".

Что делать? Подскажите!

Comment: он же у вас не установился, чего вы его запустить то пытаетесь. Запускайте команду установки еще раз, только на этот раз с двумя L. А потом уже пытайтесь запускать.

Comment: Сильно извиняюсь за не точность, вводил команду  uninstall с одной "l". Что могло удалиться в компьютере?

Comment: Спасибо. Удалил "Primavera6", Апачи перестал тупить, открылся порт 80, и роутер MGTS GPON открыл доступ к сайту.